# Special case of the Lyapunov equation $BS + SB^{\top} = kI$

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes, control-theory, sylvester-equation

In the case that we are trying to solve the Sylvester/Lyapunov equation,
$$BS + SB^{\top} = -kI$$
where $k$ is some constant positive value and $I$ is the identity, $S$ is a symmetric matrix and $B$ is a matrix - all matrices are square. is there a closed form solution for the symmetric matrix $S$? Note $B$ is not symmetric in general.

Context: the matrix $S$ represents the stationary covariance matrix of an OU-process with friction $B$ and uncorrelated, equal intensity noise terms.

Comment: Have you checked the solutions already discussed here? For instance, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4773123/rank-of-the-lyapunov-equation